# Facebook Messenger Customer Chat Plugin not appearing when not logged in

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-customer-chat

I have integrated Facebook Customer Plugin on one of our websites. I followed the instructions in the developer documentation. It is working fine when there is an active facebook session. However, the plugin does not appear at all when there is no active fb session. I might be missing something but I have no clue on what that is.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin#login seems to indicate it should still show up, so you're going to need to show us an example or some code.

Comment: hi ceejayoz. In my case, the culprit was **Country Restrictions** in the page's settings. There should be no restrictions for it to work. I have not adjusted my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

The solution for me was adding **#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1** after the **xfbml.customerchat.js** file like :

```
js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
```

Comment: If I can upvote 1000+ times for you, I will do it. You saved my life.

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Comment: Worked for me also

Comment: Worked for me. Anyone who copies this make sure to change the lang to en_US if you want english.

Comment: @Monstr92 Thank you! I updated my example so it works for more people by default!

Answer (score 2):

i solved my problem using this script :

```
<div class="fb-customerchat"
 page_id="<ENTER-YOUR-FACEBOOK-ID-HERE>"
 minimized="true">
</div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'facebook-developer-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.11'
    });
  };
(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="your-page-id"
  theme_color="#BE59B9">
</div>
```

Another case might be that, fb messenger only show when it it hosted, not locally.

For more info have a deep look at doumentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin

Comment: Please explain what is happening. Documentation would be helpful.

Comment: Where to get facebook-developer-app-id?

Answer (score 1):

It is May 2018 now, the instruction in **Page --> Settings --> Messenger platform --> Customer chat plugin** is much more clear.

Plus checking **Country Restrictions**

Answer (score 1):

I only added this code to the customer chat code provided in the page's settings:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '1175565702494581', // Trokis Philippines App ID; you may use your App ID but this App ID might work on you too.
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.11'
    });
  };
```

Original Code:

```
    <script>
(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="{your-page-id}"
  theme_color="#BE59B9">
</div>
```

Final Code:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '1175565702494581',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.11'
    });
  };
(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="{your-page-id}"
  theme_color="#BE59B9">
</div>
```

Comment: You dont need the     <div id="fb-root"></div>?

Answer (score 1):

Well, shamelessly it was the "Whitelisted Domains" that I didn't operate right.
After you insert your domain you should click "Save"...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At first I tried with a code generated by Facebook Customer Chat Plugin wizard - no luck. To make it work I had to add `FB.init` section providing valid developer `appId`:

```
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId            : 'YOUR-APP-ID-HERE',
            autoLogAppEvents : true,
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v2.11'
        });
    };
    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your customer chat code -->
  <div class="fb-customerchat"
    attribution=setup_tool
    page_id="YOUR-PAGE-ID-HERE"
    theme_color="#ed1d24"
    logged_in_greeting="Hello, how can we help you?">
  </div>
```

You can find more info on the [Facebook Customer Chat Plugin here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

For me problem was, that i had whitelisted non www domain, but opened it through www. Both cases should be added as whitelist cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using brave and probably debugging the site with included messenger plugin code. Most likely you'll find setting **Block cross-site trackers** to be **disabled**, **Block scripts** to be **disabled**, **Cookies** to be **Allow all cookies**, and lastly **Fingerprinting** to **Allow all fingerprinting** be helpful.

Once you changed the settings and you find that you have no problem in your code, then it will be most likely to work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular Framework you have to know that **you need to add your code in the index.html** page and not in the app or component. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was because my "page visibility" was set to "page unpublished". So I resolved mine by changing the "page visibility" to "page published"

page setting->General->page visibility

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution. If anyone encounters this, please check your Facebook Page's **Country Restrictions** (Settings->General->Country Restrictions). It must be available everywhere in order for the plugin to render even if there is no active session